# Bind data from outside of Itemsource of listView in xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I'm working on Xamarin.Forms, I'm facing a problem of data binding in `ListView`. There's a string value in model and a list in model, the list is the `ItemsSource` of ListView and string value should be shown in every cell row.

XMAL View

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text={Binding Name} />
                    <Label Text={Binding ConstantName} /> //// Not present in Itemsource. Should bind from Model. It does not render.
                 </Stacklayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<PagingButtons> _lstPagingButtons { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<PagingButtons> lstPagingButtons
{
    get { return _lstPagingButtons; }
    set
    {
        _lstPagingButtons = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
string _ConstantName {get; set;} = "Xamarin";
public string ConstantName 
{
    get { return _ConstantName; }
    set { __ConstantName = value; OnPropertyChange(); 
}
```

I know that I can add `ConstantName` to `PagingButtons` class but I do have this scenario for 30-40 class and it will be tedious to do that and wont be effective way to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there is a `ContentPage` around your `ListView`, but this can be any page (or even element).

Give that page a name, if it doesn't already have one, like this: `<ContentPage x:Name="MyAwesomePage" ...>`

Now, change your `Label` to this: `<Label Text={Binding BindingContext.ConstantName, Source={x:Reference Name=MyAwesomePage}} />`

This way, you refer the binding to your page's `BindingContext`, effectively changing the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
<Label Text={Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext._ConstantName}
```

Comment: Note that `_ConstantName` is the private field, so the code as presented here will not work. Also, I am not aware of the `root` keyword, but that may be missing knowledge on my part

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice it was private. I've used in the past syntax like this.

Comment: Cool, I'd have to try it. Didn't know that was possible :-) thanks!

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked, even made that field as public